# How to group by multiple column and results

Tags: sql-server

the result that I want to know is, I have a table like this:

```
(DAY 9)


+---------+----------+--------------------+
| Subject | CLOSED   | UPDATE             |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| SUB1    |        0 | 2008-11-11 13:23:44|
| SUB2    |        0 | 2008-11-11 13:23:44|
| SUB3    |        1 | 2008-11-09 13:23:44|
| SUB4    |        1 | 2008-11-09 13:23:44|
| SUB5    |        0 | 2008-11-11 13:23:44|
| SUB6    |        0 | 2008-11-10 13:23:44|
| SUB7    |        0 | 2008-11-10 13:23:44|
+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

Every day some registers are added to this table so the total of closed = 0 (default) is incresed, and I have a service that close every day some register.

```
DAY 10

+---------+----------+--------------------+
| Subject | CLOSED   | UPDATE             |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| SUB1    |        0 | 2008-11-11 13:23:44|
| SUB2    |        0 | 2008-11-11 13:23:44|
| SUB3    |        1 | 2008-11-09 13:23:44|
| SUB4    |        1 | 2008-11-09 13:23:44|
| SUB5    |        0 | 2008-11-11 13:23:44|
| SUB6    |        1 | 2008-11-10 13:23:44|
| SUB7    |        0 | 2008-11-13 13:23:44|
| SUB8    |        0 | 2008-11-13 13:23:44|
| SUB9    |        0 | 2008-11-14 13:23:44|
| SUB10   |        0 | 2008-11-15 13:23:44|
+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

etc.

What I need is something like this on the result

```
DAY | Total Modified (Closed = 1) | Total (Closed = 0)
09               2                          5
10               1                          7
11               3                          4
13               2                          2
14               1                          1
15               1                          0
```

So far I arrived on this solution

```
SELECT
DATEPART(DAY,UPDATE),
COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY (DATEPART(DAY,UPDATE))
```

What I dont know how to do is to include the column of total not modified decreasing the quantify of modified last day taking into account that on the current day some register will be added to this table.

Comment: every day data will truncate & fill another data? means day 9 data remain or not if day 10 data is fill

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time matching your expected results to the sample data, but I think you are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  [DAY]       = DATEPART(DAY, [UPDATE]),
  Modified    = SUM(CASE WHEN Closed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  NotModified = SUM(CASE WHEN Closed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM dbo.TABLE1
GROUP BY (DATEPART(DAY, [UPDATE]));
```

Just be aware that `DATEPART(DAY` will become misleading if your query spans month boundaries. Why not `CONVERT(date, [UPDATE])`?